# PHP contact form parsing error

Tags: php, contact-form

So I'm trying to learn how to build a PHP contact form on XAMPP, just a simple one that sends a name, e-mail, and message via e-mail.

So with some code I found in a couple tutorials and mixed it with some noob "I think this goes here" magic and made this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    //This is where the variables are given empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $textErr = "";
    $name = $email = $message = "";

    //The variable for the JavaScript
    $js = <<<JS
<script>
document.getElementById("contactform").style.display = "none";
</script>
JS;

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
            $nameErr = "Name is required";
        }   else    {
            $name= test_input($_POST["name"]);
        }   //this checks if the name contains only letters and whitespaces:
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            }


        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $emailErr = "Email is required";
        } else {
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        }   // this is where the e-mail address's form is checked
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
            }


        if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
            $textErr = "Aren't you going to say something?"
        }   else    {
            $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
        }

    }
    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlentities($data);
        return $data;
    }


    if ($SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($nameErr && $emailErr && $textErr)) {
            $to = "test@testmail.com";
            $subject = "Form Submission from "$name".";
            $messageall = "$message \n From: $name \n Reply to: $email";
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$from);
            echo $js;
            echo "Thanks, we will contact you back shortly!"
        }
    } 
    ?>

        <form id="contactform" method="POST" action="">
            Name:<br><input type="text" name="yourname">
            <?php echo $nameErr;><br>
            E-mail:<br><input type="text" name="youremail">
            <?php echo $emailErr;><br>
            Message:<br><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea>
            <?php echo $textErr;>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"><input type="reset" value="clear"><br>
            <?php echo $formErr;>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

So when I ran the page I got this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\index.php on line 43
```

I checked out my brackets and I'm not sure where I went wrong. I moved them around and got other parsing errors.

If someone would be help me with this issue and anything else I may have screwed up but didn't know I did yet...I'd be greatly appreciative. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You are missing the trainling semicolon at line 42 `$textErr = "Aren't you going to say something?";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it but my guess is that you're missing a semicolon on this line:

```
$textErr = "Aren't you going to say something?"
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that fixed it (well that problem at least lol).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at line 42, you'll notice that you're missing a semicolon at the end of the line therefore the } on line 43 is unexpected as it is expecting a semicolon.

Update line 42 to:

```
    $textErr = "Aren't you going to say something?";
```